# extracting values from regex

Tags: php, regex

I have this code

```
$regex = '/{tip(?:\s+class\s*=\s*"([a-zA-Z\s]+)")?}([^{]*){\/tip}/';

$matches = null;

preg_match_all($regex, $article, $matches);

if(is_array($matches)) {

 foreach ($matches as $match) {

    $article = preg_replace($regex, '<span class="tooltip $1"><i>?</i><em>$2</em></span>', $article);
   }
}
```

So I'm looking for `{tip} tip text {/tip}`, or `{tip class="someClass"} tip text{/}` and replacing it. Its works fine, but depending on class there will be different output. I need something like:

```
if (strpos($match, 'class') !== false) {

    output

} else {
    $class = $match[0];
    if ($class == 'sticked') {

        other output
    }
}
```

But i dont know how to extract class to variable, also match is an array of results, so class will be on different position every time.

Comment: Your `class` match is in a non-capture group, by the way. Maybe change it to `{tip(\s+class\s*=\s*"([a-zA-Z\s]+)")?}([^{]*){\/tip}` and switch on `$match[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$regex = '/{tip\s*([a-z]*)=?"?\'?([^\'"]*)"?\'?\s*}([^{]*){\/tip}/';
```

This way you can extract the class property with any number of spaces before or after it with \s* and with single or double quotes with "?'?

Edited to work with/without class definition. This pattern will return the property being used, so you'll still get a match if "class" is misspelled.